# Core data relationship confusion

Tags: core-data

I'm making a core data model, and I have a Client entity that has a to-many relationship to an Appointment entity. An Appointment can turn into a Transaction (if it has been paid for etc.), and I need to keep track of the Appointments of Clients that have turned into Transactions (where Transaction is an entity along with other attributes). A Client can have multiple Transactions, and a Transaction can have multiple Clients (optional). If I put a relationship between Transaction and Client, then I don't think there's a way I can detect which of the appointments have turned into transactions and which haven't...
Any help as to how I can set my model up to do this would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are more than one way of doing it. This is one I think works:

If Transaction is another entity, and Appointment has a one-to-one relationship to Transaction. Then you can leave the Transaction entity to be nil if unpaid. If paid, you set up Transaction and link up with its relationship to Appointment and Client. By checking if your Appointment's Transaction is nil, you know if it's turned into Transaction or not.

Comment: What is Entity in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you need detailed information about the transformation between the appointment and transaction you could make that transformation itself an entity and make it persistent. The new transform entity could have various properties like:

- date (when did the transformation happened)
- type (did the appointment transform into a transaction, was canceled or delayed)
- etc

and relations:

- from (the original appointment)
- to (the resulting transaction/appointment/etc)

This way the relation between client and translation would look like this

`Client->Appointent->Transform->Transaction`

If the only difference between `Appointent` and `Transaction` is being paid or not, you can consider using only `Transaction` and a flag (paid/not paid).

`Client->Transaction->Transform->Transaction`